# Minha função não está sendo executada no carregamento da página

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Estou tendo o seguinte problema sirs.

Tenho a seguinte função

```
function sortTable() {
arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.context_data);
    $('#tableLemos th').click(function () {
        console.log("funcao carregada...")
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var asc = (!$(this).attr('asc')); // switch the order, true if not set

        // set asc="asc" when sorted in ascending order
        $('#tableLemos th').each(function () {
            $(this).removeAttr('asc');
        });
        if (asc)
            $(this).attr('asc', 'asc');

        sortResults(id, asc);
    });
}
```

e também esta

```
function request(url) {
dados = [];
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    //url: "http://localhost:8080/WEB/web/configFields/" + field,
    url: url ? url : "http://localhost:8080/WEB/web/usuarios/find/",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        dados = data;
        localStorage.setItem("context_data", JSON.stringify(data));
        transform_table(JSON.stringify(data));
    }});
sortTable();
}
```

Via de regra, toda vez que eu chamar a função `request()` a função `sortTable()` deveria ser executada, porém não acontece, e detalhe se eu abrir o console do Chrome e executar a função `sortTable()` aí funciona.

Mais detalhadamente:

1. A página carrega essas funções;
2. Clico em um link que contém o evento `onClick = request()`, para chamar a função `request()`;
3. Deveria carregar o evento `click` que está dentro da função, o que não acontece sem eu abrir o console do Chrome e chamar a função por lá.

O que vocês acham?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está com um problema relacionado à falta de sincronismo. Lembre-se: AJAX é assíncrono por padrão. Portanto, se queremos que uma function seja chamada após a requisição, temos que informar isso com o ".then" desta forma:

```
function request(url) {
dados = [];
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    //url: "http://localhost:8080/WEB/web/configFields/" + field,
    url: url ? url : "http://localhost:8080/WEB/web/usuarios/find/",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        dados = data;
        localStorage.setItem("context_data", JSON.stringify(data));
        transform_table(JSON.stringify(data));
    }}).then(function(){
        sortTable();    
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hhmm compreendi amigo, quer dizer que no momento que eu chamo minha função request() o código do Ájax é executado simultaneamente com a função certo?

Isso explica muita coisa.

Obrigado!